# jQuery hide/show different elements troubleshooting

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to program a website, and now that I have designed my front, I want a link in the header saying "Portfolio" which should hide everything but the header and footer.

My HTML is as such:

```
    <div class="header" id="front-show">
        <div class="header-kevin-vfx">
            <a href="#"><h1 id="front-show">Kevin VFX</h1></a>
        </div>

        <div class="header-portfolio"  id="portfolio-show">
            <a href="#"><h1>Portfolio</h1></a>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="site-title hidden">
        <h1>Kevin VFX</h1>
        <p>Marketing the modern way</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        <p>Click a video thumbnail to watch a video</p>
    </div>
</div>    

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>Copyright 2016 © Kevin From</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
    div.content-wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    top:50%;left:50%;
}

div.header {
    z-index:3;
    height:70px;
    background-color:rgba(204,204,204,0.3);
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}

div.header a h1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgba(250,250,250,0.7);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.header a h1:hover {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

div.header div.header-kevin-vfx {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding-left:7px;
}

div.header div.header-portfolio{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    padding-right:7px;
} 

div.footer {
    z-index:3;
    height:30px;
    background-color:rgba(204,204,204,0.3);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}

div.footer div.copyright p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

and last my scripts are:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('div.portfolio-wrapper').hide();        
$('div.hidden')
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .slideUp(500)
        .slideDown(500)
        .removeClass('hidden');
});

$('#front-show').onclick(function () {
    $('.portfolio-wrapper').hide(500).delay(500);
    $('.content-wrapper').show(500);
});

$('#portfolio-show').onclick(function () {
    $('.content-wrapper').hide(500).delay(500);
    $('.portfolio-wrapper').show(500);
});
```

Thank you very much for your help, in advance! -Kevin

Comment: There is no `onclick()` function on Jquery it must be `.click()` or  `.on('click', function())`

Comment: It's better if you bind the function to the anchor tag check this https://jsfiddle.net/9zxzwedt/

Comment: I tried changing up the scripts and html to match yours in the fiddle, but still no change. I also downloaded Boostrap and jQuery onto my computer instead, because I'm running on slow internet at the moment.

Comment: I made the script in-line instead of a seperate script document, and now it works - so now I'll just clean up and tidy up my website. Thanks for your help, both of you. -Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#front-show').find('.content-wrapper, .portfolio-wrapper').hide();
```

Comment: Do you want me to add an an ID on my anchor tags, and then use the script you send, or should I use the ID's on the DIVs that contain my anchor tags?

Comment: You could just use your existing div.  I was thinking you wanted to add a link, see updated answer in a sec

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: i dont have a fiddle, no